# Ubuntu - no audio after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, ubuntu-13.10

I upgraded Ubuntu to 13.10 yesterday and guess what? No more audio! Hooray!

So I visited all possible posts ([there are many](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361730/no-sounds-after-upgrade)) on the subject but none of the suggested alternatives worked for me. [The most common suggestion](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) I see is uninstalling and then reinstalling *alsa* and *pulse*:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
$ sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
$ sudo alsa force-reload
```

Didn't do it. [Another suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/365983) was deleting the folder */run/user/{my_user_id}/pulse*, but that didn't have any effect either.

The result of `sudo aplay -l` is the same as that of `aplay -l` (without *sudo*):

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC662 rev3 Analog [ALC662 rev3 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about askubuntu.

Comment: After upgrade 13.1, I was forced to leave ubuntu and switch to mint because of the same reasons.

Comment: Is this a desktop or a laptop? Is it the main speakers or headphones? Not enough information in the post to provide meaningful help/

Comment: Do you have a programming question?

Comment: No, I don't have any programming question. And if you "hardcore {whatever}/experts" think this question is not suitable for stackoverflow, feel free to move it to wherever you want (stackexchange, serverfault etc).

Comment: We are unable to move it to http://askubuntu.com/ so you should go there and ask a new question.

Comment: You kidding me, right? Where's the rule saying that stackoverflow and askubuntu are mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can most likely use hda-jack-retask to fix it (http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/pulseaudio-discuss/2011-December/012342.html). Go through each pin (including un-assigned ones), try setting them as speakers, playing a music file from beginning, and rinse/repeat until you find the working pin.

Comment: Thanks, Srdjan. It's in fact a desktop computer.

Comment: Edit: I've had the same issue with my laptop but the instructions should apply to desktops too

Comment: Also once you find the right pins, make sure to set it to be hooked on boot. Another thing to note is that sometimes the Output pane of Sound Settings does not get updated correctly on headphone plugging/unplugging so you need to manually switch sometimes

Comment: Solved problem with hda-jack-retask, which is now part of alsa-tools. So I installed alsa-tools-gui and tweaked the options until the jacks started working again.

For more info on the package: https://launchpad.net/~diwic/+archive/hda